# Facebook log in works only after deleting cookies:Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration Facebook application error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been using facebook login option on my website for about 3 months now. Everything worked fine. But today I am getting the error:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

**This happens when the user is already logged into facebook.** If the user needs to login the sign in works fine as before. Alternatively clearing out the cookies also works, makes the facebook log in work as before.

This happened by itself without any changes to app settings on facebook. I have gone through the other questions on SO and can't seem to figure this out. Any ideas?

```
$(function() {
  $('body').prepend('<div id="fb-root"></div>');
  return $.ajax({
    url: "" + window.location.protocol + "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js",
    dataType: 'script',
    cache: true
  });
});

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId: '123456789098765434',
    cookie: true
  });
  $('#sign_in').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return FB.login((function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        return window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback';
      }
    }), {
      scope: 'email,user_likes'
    });
  });
  return $('#sign_out').click(function(e) {
    FB.getLoginStatus(response);
    return true;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you hosting the Facebook JS locally?

If so, it could be the same issue as I had and you need to change it to source the JS from Facebook, e.g.

src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"

Comment: I am using this but I have enabled caching. I have updated my question with the js I am using. That might help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem (but in PHP sdk) and I found that there was a mismatch in my "redirect_uri" and "Valid OAuth redirect URIs".

In my code, I had set:

```
redirect_uri = "http://www.website.com/validate.php";
```

But in my Facebook app I had set Valid OAuth redirect URIs:

```
http://website.com/validate.php
```

All I was missing "www". So I added another Valid OAuth redirect URI in my Facebook app:

```
http://www.website.com/validate.php
```